# JMeter If Controller jexl3

Tags: jmeter

In an IfController

```
${__jexl3("${usecase}" == "month")} # works (true) when $usecase = months

${__jexl3("${usecase}" == "month")} # do not work when $usecase = quarter?
```

Instead, I get

```
2021-05-18 16:17:57,863 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[MonthTable 1-1,6,main] java.lang.StackOverflowError: null   at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:163) ~[?:?]   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext(JMeterContextService.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]   at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.SimpleVariable.getVariables(SimpleVariable.java:64) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.SimpleVariable.toString(SimpleVariable.java:50) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:144) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Jexl3Function.execute(Jexl3Function.java:72) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:100) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:280) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]   at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.getCondition(IfController.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:175) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]  at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]  at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]  at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
```

/Best regards, Mats

Comment: Welcome to the community!  It will help you to get better answers if your question is better formulated. Explain what you have, what is the expected behavior, and what have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `${usecase}` variable does really have the value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree Listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) as looking at the error it is not the case.

I cannot reproduce your issue using the same JMeter version

[image]

For non-defined variable it cannot be reproduced either.

Try getting a [clean vanilla JMeter installation](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) without any plugins and if the issue is still reproducible maybe it's connected with your [Java version](https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-Java-Version), in that case seeing your [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks, it helped to decrease number of variables in my script so probably some sort of bug.